# Checking of enumerables in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a way in Jest to check iterable object (with `[Symbol.iterator]` method) using array-like notation?

Like this:

```
expect(new Matrix).toBe([
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
])
```

Where `Matrix` is not an array, but has the `[Symbol.iterator]` method:

```
class Matrix {
  public *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield new Vector(1, 0, 0)
    yield new Vector(0, 1, 0)
    yield new Vector(0, 0, 1)
  }
}
```

In this example it is important that approach should be recursive, as each (yielded) element of the object may also be iterable:

```
class Vector {
  private values : number[]

  public constructor(values : number[]) {
    this.values = values
  }

  public *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    return yield this.values
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small utility that consumes an iterator recursively and returns a nested array. Example:

```js
 let consumed = x => (x && typeof x === 'object' && x[Symbol.iterator])
     ? [...x].map(consumed) : x;

//

class Matrix {
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield new Vector(1, 0, 0)
        yield new Vector(0, 1, 0)
        yield new Vector(0, 0, 1)
    }
}

class Vector {

    constructor(...values) {
        this.values = values
    }

    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* this.values
    }
}



m = consumed(new Matrix())
console.log(m)
```

and in your tests use `expect(consumed(someMatrix)).toBe...`

Answer (score 0):

The test can rely on a way that iterables are expected to behave in JavaScript:

```
const matrix = new Matrix();

expect(matrix[Symbol.iterator]).toEqual(expect.any(Function));
expect([...matrix]).toEqual([
  expect.any(Vector),
  expect.any(Vector),
  expect.any(Vector),
]);

expect([...matrix].map(row => [...row]).toEqual([
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
]);
```

Alternatively, `Vector` can be mocked and tested separately.